# check if a desired URL with an specified QueryString is now online or not?

Tags: asp.net, url, vb.net-2010

I want to check if a `URL` with an specified `QueryString` is now online or not?
I know there is a way to check just the online(alive) websites:

```
     Try
            Dim myHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://www.example.com"), HttpWebRequest)
            Dim myHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            myHttpWebResponse.Close()
            ''Some codes
      Catch
            ''Some codes
      End Try
```

Comment: You can pass anything via querystring to a url. It is upto the page whether it processes that querystring value or not. So there is no way to tell what querystring variables a page has/processes other than observing its behavior, or otherwise you get it anywhere from any link on that website (assuming that they will always have valid URL to at-least their own pages).

Comment: ... Or maybe if I got it wrong, you may want to rephrase your question.

Comment: What is your question? How to perform a web request to an URI containing query string values? Just as you do, except `WebRequest.Create("https://www.example.com&foo=bar")`. If your question is _"How can I determine, based on the response, that that URI exists"_, then you need to define "exists".

Comment: Now after your edit, it becomes more confusing. What does `online` mean? If a website is up (online), and the page you want to access exists, you can pass it any querystring you want. You will always get a response irrespective your querystring made any effect or not.

Comment: I want to check each useris online or not by using QueryString.

Comment: Which website are you accessing? How do you tell it the username? And how does the website report you back the user status?

Comment: I want to test it first on my own webpage. Not need to check it on other websites. In the first page I redirected it to the second page: ` Response.Redirect("Test.aspx?ID=" + TextBox1.Text)`  Now it has a new query string. I want now check if there is a username with that QueryString or not?

Comment: So how do you tell your webpage the username whose status you want to get? And how does your webpage tell you the status of that user?

Comment: For example I want to check if a name like pencil is there or not.

Comment: So for example, you pass the username in querystring (say, http://www.example.com/CheckUserStatus.aspx?user=pencil). How does our page tell you back whether this user is online or not?

Comment: Yes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

So your actual question is something like this:

> Given a web page that gives a response based on query string parameters, how can I determine that this response is positive?

That depends on how the page is implemented. Some sites, such as the Stack Overflow Users page, gives a 404 response when the requested user does not exist, as can be seen from this URI: `http://stackoverflow.com/users/7000000`.

Inspecting a 404 response is trivial, and gives you the information you need.

When the site doesn't give a 404 but a plain old 200 with somewhere on the page the text "That user doesn't exist", you'll have to parse the HTML to find that string, hope they don't perform localization and assume they never change the page.

Alternatively, given you say:

> on my own webpage. Not need to check it on other websites.

You can instead implement a small web service. You can do this any way you like, and then perform a GET to an URI like this: `http://example.com/UserService?UserID=42`.

Then you'll make the service return the proper HTTP status code, and interpret that by inspecting the response.